# How to save details in the New Individual Form, if the contact is Self Employed or is a Student

Tags: individual, data

I was entering Contact Data and after Name details the next thing i noticed the Current Employer Field but I had Contacts who were

1. Self Employed/Freelancers
2. Students

How do I Save their data?

Answer (score 1):

To create an individual contact the basic details you need are First Name and Last Name, or Email Address.

You should be able to leave the employer field blank and still create a contact.

Comment: But if someone has modified the Profile that is being used for New Individual, and made Employer a required field, then you should be able to find that Profile and change it back

Comment: What Pete Said...

Under standard civicrm settings it shouldn't matter if a contact has an employer or not.

If your site has been modified to make the current employer field "required", you could struggle.

Can you take a screenshot of the profile/ page that your using? And paste it into your question.